# Is there any option to check whether the application is valid or not in playstore

Tags: android, suspend

Last week I uploaded new version of my app. But Google suspended my app from playstore without any information.

Is there any way to check application is valid before publish app?

Is anyone notice this problem?. Please give your suggestion for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: usually You get a message to Your email account if an app would be removed from google because of some not allowed content..

Comment: Yes. But get message after suspended. Why they did not inform before suspension?

Comment: there is a reclamation mark inside a triangle on the left side in your developer conole, there You get the warning before getting email.